# Sorting by expression from NSExpressionDescription

Tags: ios, core-data

Is it possible to sort data by expression from `NSExpressionDescription`?

Answer (score 1):

No, [`NSSortDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is used to sort results.

[Based on the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSExpressionDescription_Class/NSExpressionDescription.html), `NSExpressionDescription` is used to further narrow your search.

> An `NSExpressionDescription` describes a column to be returned from a
>   fetch that may not appear directly as an attribute or relationship on
>   an entity. Examples might include `upper(attribute)` or
>   `max(attribute)`. You cannot set an `NSExpressionDescription` object
>   as a property of an entity.

[Fetching Managed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html) provides some code examples of `NSExpressionDescription` and `NSSortDescriptor`. Here's a snippet of the `NSSortDescriptor` example.

```
// Set example predicate and sort orderings...
NSNumber *minimumSalary = ...;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"(lastName LIKE[c] 'Worsley') AND (salary > %@)", minimumSalary];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
    initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```